# Copy data from all workbooks in a folder to a summary list with links to the data

Tags: excel, hyperlink, summarization, vba

I'm trying to copy a lot of workbooks into a summary workbook, I've gotten the below code to do the job so far.

```
Option Explicit


Const FOLDER_PATH = "Folderpath\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH

Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   rowTarget = Sheets("Status").Cells(Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   'On Error GoTo errHandler
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'set up the target worksheet
   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Status")

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Side 1-Forside") 'EDIT IF NECESSARY

      'import the data
      With wsTarget
         .Activate
         wsSource.Range("C14").Copy
         .Range("A" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("C15").Copy
         .Range("B" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("C13").Copy
         .Range("C" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("I11").Copy
         .Range("J" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("I10").Copy
         .Range("K" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("C40").Copy
         .Range("L" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("E40").Copy
         .Range("M" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         wsSource.Range("I9").Copy
         .Range("H" & rowTarget).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
         'optional source filename in the last column

            .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
      End With

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

'errHandler:
   'On Error Resume Next
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub


Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

However is it possible to  grab the data as a link instead of a "dead" value? So if it gets changed in one of the many workbooks, I just have to refresh the summary workbook?

Bonusquestion: Is it possible to check for duplicates in this bit: `.Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value = sFile` and only add if the values isn't there already and the new values should add from the last empty row below row 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the source range and then use *Special Paste › Paste Link* in the destination workbook. It pastes a formula linking to the source workbooks copied range.
[This short YouTube video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=_YgCJb2FF-4) should illustrate it best.

You could also do that with VBA if necessary e.g:

```
wsSource.Range("C14").Copy
.Range("A" & rowTarget).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
```

It seems like we need to `.Select` first and use `ActiveSheet.Paste` otherwise the link pasting fails, even if that looks like a bad practice, but the below direct referencing the range won't work!

```
wsSource.Range("C14").Copy
.Range("A" & rowTarget).Paste Link:=True 'fails with error 438
```

But because you are linking the values now with a formula you probably need to do that only once and therefore don't need the VBA solution anymore, because it is easier to do it **once** by hand.

**Note:**
be aware that these workbooks are linked by a formula then. If you move the source workbook into another location the link will break (if the destination workbook is not within the same location and copied as well). This comes with all the downsides of linked workbooks.

---

//edit

```
With wsTarget
    .Activate
    .Range("A" & rowTarget).Select
    wsSource.Range("C14").Copy 
    .Paste Link:=True
    .Activate
    .Range("B" & rowTarget).Select
    wsSource.Range("C15").Copy        
    .Paste Link:=True
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and solution suggestion, I've got about 43 workbooks I need to add, and more will be added, however the workbooks will always be in this folder.

Comment: I've added the code as I believe it is supposed to, however it still doesn't create links between the two workbooks. Am I misunderstanding, how this works or have I used your suggested codesnippet wrongly?

Comment: @FoolzRailer Oh my snippet is 2 lines you did it in one line that is something completely different. You cannot strip out line breaks where you want to. That changes the logic of the code completely.

Comment: Lesson 101 in coding VBA just learned, appreciated that :) Changed it to the above, but when I run it now, it opens the first workbook which it is supposed to copy from and the first cell in the code (C14) is marked, but it just stops there.

Comment: @FoolzRailer "*just stops there*" with which error message? Code never just stops without an error message unless you are in step-by-step mode.

Comment: There is no error message popping up, it just opens up the first workbook, copies the cell and pauses with that workbook open and cell copied. Is there anyway I give you more information from when the code is running?

Comment: Ok obviously there is an error, and because of `On Error GoTo errHandler` it jumps to `errHandler` but there you just end without validating which error occurred, so it keeps silent and you are blind. So either rise the error again at the `errHandler` section with eg `Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext` or give at least a custom message like `MsgBox "Import canceled due to Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext` If you use error handling always make sure you give a message, or you are blind.

Comment: Well right you are Peh, I removed the error handler, and when I run the code I get a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. When I hit debug it refers to the line: 
`.Range("A" & rowTarget).Paste Link:=True`

Comment: I didn't expect that, as that's very odd but for pasting links the target range needs to be selected first (probably you need to activate the sheet too after line `With wsTarget` insert one `.Activate`) and then we have to use `ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True`. It looks like links cannot be pasted on a direct reference. See my updated answer.

Comment: This works, though occasionally it says it doesn't have a link to paste, even though it has marked a cell. Would it work putting in a small pause between copy-paste bit? Or would that be a terrible idea? I'm thinking it can't open the excel-workbooks fast enough perhaps?

Comment: Forgot the error code. Run-time error '1004': No link to paste: When I debug it selects different lines `wsSource.Range("I11").Copy` and `wsSource.Range("I10").Copy` . Which is why i propose the pause. I've also changed rowtarget I think I did it correctly so it now takes the first empty cell. Is there any way to check for duplicates as I've added in my question as well?

Comment: The error 1004 means that it lost the copy mode, why ever. Are there any selection change events in `wsTarget` that might kill the copy mode? Checking duplicates is not possible with paste link. If you want to do that you need to write your own paste link and cannot use the one of Excel (this would be a completely other question).

Comment: Doesn't appear so, the source workbook is opened and the cell is copied. It works for the first 5-6 workbooks (varies) and stopswith the I11 or I10 cell bit. It seems random which of the workbooks it stops at. Have I put in the `.activate` correctly?

Comment: yes code looks ok for me. But just in case your sheet looses activation try what I showed in my edit (activate before every select, remove activesheet and reorder). This could help to stabilize it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to the one suggested by Peh, both work, though the one below is not as flexible but hardcoded instead. Thought I would share.

```
Option Explicit


Const FOLDER_PATH = "Folderpath\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH

Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row

   rowTarget = Sheets("Status").Cells(Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   'On Error GoTo errHandler
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'set up the target worksheet
   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Status")

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'import the data
      With wsTarget

         'optional source filename in the last column
         .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
         .Range("A" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$C$14"
         .Range("B" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$C$15"
         .Range("C" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$C$13"
         .Range("J" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$I$11"
         .Range("K" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$I$10"
         .Range("L" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$C$40"
         .Range("M" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$E$40"
         .Range("H" & rowTarget).Value = "=" & "'" & FOLDER_PATH & "[" & .Range("AK" & rowTarget).Value & "]" & "Side 1-Forside" & "'" & "!$I$9"

      End With

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop

'errHandler:
   'On Error Resume Next
   'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End Sub


Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this AddIn.  It will do exactly what you want.

[image]

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm